# MSSQL SERIALIZABLE Transaction with Range-Lock

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get range-lock working with entity framework. Let's say i have a table with the following columns:

```
| Id    | int   |
| Type  | int   |
| Value | int   |
```

Where `Id` is a PRIMARY KEY with CLUSTERED INDEX and `Type` has a NON-CLUSTERED NOT-UNIQUE INDEX.

If I want to select a value within serializable transaction using this code

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT Value  FROM MyTable WHERE Type = 5

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE  request_session_id = @@SPID AND resource_type = 'KEY'
COMMIT
```

It correctly range-locks a row with `Type = 5` and next row.

If I do this query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT Id, Type, Value FROM MyTable WHERE Type = 5

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE  request_session_id = @@SPID AND resource_type = 'KEY'
COMMIT
```

It locks all rows. Unfortunately Entity Framwork selects all columns:

```
SELECT [Id], [Type], [Value] FROM ...
```

I am filtering my real table on a column with FOREIGN KEY and this column is not unique. I tried to make my NON-CLUSTERED INDEX on the `Type` column UNIQUE and it locks the correct rows even when I select all columns.

How can I get same with NON UNIQUE INDEX?

Comment: It seems if i specity NON-UNIQUE INDEX, execution plan choose CLUSTERED INDEX and LOCK all rows. I know I can write INDEX HINT, but Entity Framework does not support these hints.

Answer (score 1):

What is locked depends on the query plan. Everything that the plan reads is subject to locking. So you need to make SQL Server find the index that you want to lock on attractive. Start by creating an optimal index for that query.

Why do you want a specific locking pattern to occur? If it's for performance reasons that is totally valid. If it's for behavioral reasons that is quite unreliable.

You also can make EF select less columns by not selecting entities but DTP objects (e.g. anonymous types).

Comment: Specific locking pattern is because performance and also there are two sources, which can make a duplicated row. Will check anonymous types if it helps.

Comment: SERIALIZABLE guarantees as if serial execution. There will be no duplicates if you check before insert.

Comment: usr: yes, of course that's correct :) the problem is range locking all rows instead rows given by WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pity, SERIALIZABLE transaction can't do range lock with Clustered Index when WHERE clause contains different columns which have NON-UNIQUE INDEX or NO INDEX.

I found a nice workaround for Entity Framework.

If you want to LOCK ROWS with specific values, for example all rows with Type=FINISHED, make a NON-UNIQUE index ( if the column can contain duplicates ).

We have to tell to SQL DB what INDEX we should use.

```
var tables = context.MyTables.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WITH(INDEX(MyIndex)) WHERE Type='FINISHED'").ToList();
```

I used WITH(INDEX(MyIndex)), so it locks all rows where Type='FINISHED' even it has NON-UNIQUE INDEX

Perhaps someone will bring better solution than RAW QUERY.

EDIT: Rangelock uses NON-UNIQUE INDEX without any problem. It did not use because not enough data in the database.